# How to segregate higher numbers from lower numbers

Tags: python, comparison

```
import random
num = input('enter a number:') 
n1=random.randrange(0,50)
n2=random.randrange(0,50)
n3=random.randrange(0,50)
n4=random.randrange(0,50)
n5=random.randrange(0,50)
```

What i want to do is to compare those random numbers to my input number if the random number is higher it will be displayed all higher numbers than the user input also, it will display the smaller numbers compare to the user input at the same time
For example i entered
30
And the random numbers are 5, 45, 18, 22, 50
Output:
Higher number than 30 are: 45, 50
Lower number than 30 are: 5, 18, 22

I tried using if else but it wont display anything if the series of numbers are mixed like the example.

Comment: Please update your question with some sample data and its corresponding output that you require.

Comment: Also show us what you have tried so far to solve the problem.

Comment: Why not just print all the numbers anyway? `print(n1, n2, n3, n4, n5)`

Answer (score 1):

```
import random
num = input('enter a number:') 
random_numbers = []

# Generate all the numbers and store in a list
for i in range (0,5):
    random_numbers.append(random.randrange(0,50))

# Get lower values
lower = [number for number in random_numbers if number<num]
# Get higher ones 
higher = [number for number in random_numbers if number>num]

print("Higher number than {num} are: " + str(higher))
print("Lower number than {num} are: " + str(lower))
```

Answer (score 0):

An elegant way is to use *Numpy* module.

Instead of creating individual values, create a *Numpy* (1-d) array:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.random.randint(0, 50, 5)
```

(*5* values between *0* and *50*). Assume that the result is:

```
array([ 0,  1, 23, 42, 47])
```

Then, assuming that the threshold value (*num*) == 30, to get values
<= or > from this value, run:

```
arr[arr <= num]
arr[arr > num]
```

The result is:

```
array([ 0,  1, 23])
array([42, 47])
```

If you want plain *Python* lists instead of *Numpy* arrays, run:

```
arr[arr <= num].tolist()
arr[arr > num].tolist()
```